# Performance monitor react native

Tags: react-native

I'm noticing the "dropped so far" number in the perf monitor constantly increasing up. It reached 2030fps.

Is this number supposed to increase constantly? or I have something wrong in my app.

Answer (score 1):

It will generally increase over time but you want that number to be as low as possible. Basically every javascript action is bundled within 16ms intervals and sent to the main thread, anytime a javascript action takes longer than that it's considered a dropped frame because the main thread no has to wait for the next 16ms batch. Every 16ms results in 1 more dropped frame.

So for example say you have a component that has a slide in animation, and does some work on `componentDidMount` and that works takes 60ms. That means that if your animation is happening on the javascript thread it will stutter for 4 frames (which is definitely perceptible).

Go through your app and see which renders cause the app to drop frames, then check out the render logic for those components. It's likely that you should be using `shouldComponentUpdate` or even better `PureComponent` to prevent wasted renders.

[More info here!](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance)

Comment: Thank you but even no action is performed on the screen the frames are dropping continuously. and i left the app open for 7+ hours and no actions are being performed 40,000+ frames are dropped in that time. Why is that happening?

Comment: do you have some background code running? maybe you have some event listeners that you didn't remove or some headless javascript? 7 hours is a LONG time, I would restart the app fresh, clear all your caches, and use it for 30 minutes going through your features and see what happens